# In my project layers that were originally created by a Garmin 62s are projected 300 degrees/100m differently to the background mapping can you help?

Tags: coordinate-system, offset

In my project layers that were originally created by a Garmin 62s  are projected 300 degrees offset and 100m distant to the background mapping can you help?
When I had these display problems in 'A Coruna' I found a combination of different CRS that would give an acurate display but now in Hanover I have a problem. The Garmin layers are currently saved as ESRI shapefiles with a CRS of EPSG: 4326 and the background mapping from the UK Ordnance Survey as EPSG: 27700. The project CRS is EPSG: 27700. I have swapped all these CRS around but can't find a combination that doesn't either distort the background mapping or offset the other layers.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen. Also, information on your project area would be useful.

Comment: I presume A Coruña and Hannover are QGIS versions. Am I right? In that case it would be a good idea mentioning you are using that software.